# Second PHP session starting through AJAX call on first load

Tags: php, ajax, sessionid

I'm currently trying to set up my first website and I'm having an issue with the PHP sessions. When I first load the page in a browser, I include a .php file in the  and then call another through ajax. My problem is that the php file called through AJAX is starting a second session with a different session_id. Both the php files are in the directory above the public_html directory, which is where the index.php file resides. If I refresh the page with a ctrl+F5, there is no problem, the two files return the same session number. I have stripped all my code down to the bare bones and have run out of ideas in resolving this issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It just occurred to me that I call a file1.php file in public_html with AJAX, which then calls a file1.php in the directory above as I could not see any other way to call the latter php file through AJAX. Could this be the cause of the problem? file1.php in public_html is simply:

```
<?php
    include('../file1.php');
?>
```

Here is the code:

Index.php (home page's html file containing php):

```
<head>

<?php
    include("../file1.php");
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlfile2=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlfile2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlgetfile2.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlfile2.readyState ==4 && xmlfile2.status==200){    
                var response = xmlfile2.responseText;
                alert(response);
                document.getElementById("userID").innerHTML= response;
            }
        }
        xmlfile2.open("GET","file2.php",true);
        xmlfile2.send();
</script>

</head>
```

file1.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "session_id file1: " . session_id();
?>
```

file2.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "session_id file2: " . session_id();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session has to be started right at the beginning, to a conclusion of any symbols. In your code at first there is a conclusion `<head>`, and then already session.

In general the problem can be and not because of it, but it is better to start session in the top. In addition the problem can be in settings of sessions. I had a similar problem when I manually kept session in files

Comment: Note that index.php is an html file that contains some php (I'll edit to clarify). The "<head>" is part of the html code. In the full code there are some lines of code to load things like javascript files before the "<?php line". The first line of file1.php is "session_start()".

Comment: You were right! I eventually moved the php include not only outside the <head>, but also before the document declaration and it is all working fine now. Thank you!